# AWS EC2 websocket over https not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, websocket, simplewebrtc

websocket on my ec2 instance working fine with http://live.talkrecruit.com:8888/socket.io/
However i am not able to connect it over ssl
https://live.talkrecruit.com:8888/socket.io/ and ssl is installed correctly on this instance which works fine on default port https://live.talkrecruit.com

Please help

Comment: How can you have both HTTPS and HTTP on the _same_ port 8888?

Comment: okay, i only want to keep https, how do i change it? i am using aws ec2 instance.